# Как добавить данные из таблицы в запрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вот готовая часть кода, она работает корректно. Выводит сотрудника, кол-во звонков и общее время в диалоге с абонентом. В этот запрос я хочу добавить данные из другой таблицы, данные о перерыве. Сколько минут находится в перерыве.

```
 declare @id table (id uniqueidentifier)
    insert into @id
    select id from [oktell_settings].[dbo].[A_Users]
    where ParentGroupID = @group

    Select US.Name,Tb2.[CountCall],Tb2.[TIme]
    FROM
    (
    Select Count(id) [CountCall], oktell.dbo.GetTimeFromSecond(sum(Time)) [TIme], [UserId]
    FROM
    (
    select id, datediff(ss,TimeAnswer, TimeStop) [Time], AUserId [UserId]
      FROM [oktell].[dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1]
      where AuserID in (select * from @id)
      and TimeStart between @dt1 and @dt2    
        and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeStart, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2           

    Union All

    select  id, datediff(ss,TimeAnswer, TimeStop) [Time], BUserId [UserId]
      FROM [oktell].[dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1]
      where BuserID in (select * from @id)
      and TimeStart between @dt1 and @dt2 
        and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeStart, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2           

      )Tb1
    Group BY [UserId]
    )Tb2,
    [oktell_settings].[dbo].[A_Users] US
    Where Tb2.UserId = US.Id
    Order by name asc

Я пробовал вот так сделать.

declare @id table (id uniqueidentifier)
insert into @id
select id from [oktell_settings].[dbo].[A_Users]
where ParentGroupID = @group

Select US.Name,Tb2.[CountCall],Tb2.[TIme], Tb2.[LengthSec]
FROM
(
Select Count(id) [CountCall], oktell.dbo.GetTimeFromSecond(sum(Time)) [TIme], [LengthSec], [UserId] 
FROM
(
select kk.id, datediff(ss,TimeAnswer, kk.TimeStop) [Time], kk.AUserId [UserId] , ee.LengthSec [LengthSec]
  FROM [oktell].[dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1] kk, [A_CallCenter_UserStateHistory] ee
  where kk.AuserID in (select * from @id)
  and kk.TimeStart between @dt1 and @dt2    
    and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), kk.TimeStart, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2 
    and OperatorId=kk.AuserID and State=3 and ee.TimeEnter between @dt1 and @dt2 and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), ee.TimeEnter, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2   

Union All

select  tt.id, datediff(ss,TimeAnswer, tt.TimeStop) [Time], tt.BUserId [UserId] , ww.LengthSec [LengthSec]
  FROM [oktell].[dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1] tt, [A_CallCenter_UserStateHistory] ww
  where tt.BuserID in (select * from @id)
  and tt.TimeStart between @dt1 and @dt2 
    and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), tt.TimeStart, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2    
    and OperatorId=tt.BuserID and State=3 and ww.TimeEnter between @dt1 and @dt2 and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), ww.TimeEnter, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2           

  )Tb1
Group BY [UserId] , [LengthSec]
)Tb2,
[oktell_settings].[dbo].[A_Users] US
Where Tb2.UserId = US.Id
Order by name asc
```

Потом вот так пробовал, ну не получается, как его правильно отредактировать?

```
Select US.Name,Tb2.[CountCall],Tb2.[TIme], ee.LengthSec
FROM
(
Select Count(id) [CountCall], oktell.dbo.GetTimeFromSecond(sum(Time)) [TIme], [UserId]
FROM
(
select id, datediff(ss,TimeAnswer, TimeStop) [Time], AUserId [UserId]
  FROM [oktell].[dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1]
  where AuserID in (select * from @id)
  and TimeStart between @dt1 and @dt2    
    and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeStart, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2           

Union All

select  id, datediff(ss,TimeAnswer, TimeStop) [Time], BUserId [UserId]
  FROM [oktell].[dbo].[A_Stat_Connections_1x1]
  where BuserID in (select * from @id)
  and TimeStart between @dt1 and @dt2 
    and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), TimeStart, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2           

  )Tb1
Group BY [UserId]
)Tb2,
[oktell_settings].[dbo].[A_Users] US, [A_CallCenter_UserStateHistory] ee
Where Tb2.UserId = US.Id and ee.OperatorId in (select * from @id) and ee.State=3 and ee.TimeEnter between @dt1 and @dt2 and CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), ee.TimeEnter, 108) AS DATETIME) between @tm1 and @tm2
Order by name asc
```

Вот сама таблица, которую я хочу впихнуть. Понятное дело, что надо брать все записи от даты до даты и складывать их, перевожу в минуты и вывожу на каждого сотрудника.

В этой таблице получали время диалога и суммировали.

Да таблицы связаны.

```
[A_Stat_Connections_1x1] - таблица хранящая информацию о состоявшихся разговорах
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] - id записи
[IdChain] [uniqueidentifier] - id цепочки коммутаций (звонка)
[TimeStart] [datetime] - время начала коммутации
[TimeAnswer] [datetime] - время ответа
[TimeStop] [datetime] - время конца коммутации
[ALineNum] [nvarchar](10) -  А (IVR если А это IVR)
[BLineNum] [nvarchar](10) -  В (IVR если В это IVR)
[AUserId] [uniqueidentifier] - Id пользователя (bf-внешняя линия, ab  IVR)
[BUserId] [uniqueidentifier] - Id пользователя  (bf- внешняя линия, ab IVR)

В этой таблице как раз и есть то что мне надо, продолжительность нахождения в перерыве. 

[A_CallCenter_UserStateHistory] — история входа\выхода пользователей в\из Call-центра

[Id] [uniqueidentifier] — ID записи
[OperatorId] [uniqueidentifier] — ID пользователя
[State] [int] — состояние (0 - Система, 1 - Call-центр, 2 - Онлайн, 3 - Перерыв, 4 - Ручной режим Call-центра)
[TimeEnter] [datetime] — дата входа (установки нового состояния)
[TimeLeave] [datetime] — дата выхода (смены состояния)
[LengthSec] [float] — продолжительность нахождения в состоянии
[Info] [nvarchar](100) — причина перерыва при выборе причины «Прочие» указывается вручную
```

Comment: Приведите образцы таблиц ваших что-ли. чтобы понятнее было.

Comment: таблицы связаны?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я дополнил